# Convert array<Byte> to Struct in managed CPP

Tags: arrays, struct, c++-cli, managed

This has to be one of the most common things to do when working with IP Sockets. You get the data as a array and then you probably need to convert it to a struct.

The code looks something like this:

```
    array<Byte> ^ buffer = gcnew array<Byte>(2048);

while( nDataLen < 16 )
{
    nDataLen += m_Socket->Receive( buffer, 16-nDataLen, SocketFlags::None );
    m_Socket->Poll( 100000, SelectMode::SelectRead );
}
```

Now I need to take the 16 Bytes I just received and convert them to the following struct;

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind::Explicit, Size=16, Pack=1,CharSet=CharSet::Ansi)]
public ref struct ResponseHeader
{
   public:

[FieldOffset(0)]    
UInt32  m_StartMessage;     // STRP

[FieldOffset(4)]    
Int32   m_MessageLength;    //  Total message length

[FieldOffset(8),MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::ByValTStr,SizeConst=6)]    
String ^    m_Status;       //  Message Status

[FieldOffset(14),MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::ByValTStr,SizeConst=2)]   
String ^    m_Reason;       //  Message Reason

};
```

I would like to see a cast from the array directly to the struct but I am not sure that is doable in managed code, simple in native cpp.

If there isn't a way to cast this, then what is the best way to proceed?

Comment: It is so common that most programmers use a library and a data format that is not so platform dependent.  You can hack it with GCHandle::Alloc/AddrOfPinnedObject and Marshal::PtrToStructure().